# Prove or disprove: $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}/ \mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$ , where $\mathcal{N}$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an ultrafilter on $\omega$ containing the set $\{1, 3, 5\}$. Prove or disprove: $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}/ \mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic
to $\mathcal{N}$ , where $\mathcal{N}$ is the standard model of natural numbers (with Peano axioms).

1. elements of $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}$
   are functions $f : \omega \rightarrow  \mathbb{N}$
2. $\mathcal{N}^{\omega}/ \mathcal{F}$ are equivalence classes $f_{\mathcal{F}}$
3. $f_{\mathcal{F}} = \{ g \in \mathbb{N}^{\omega}: f =_{\mathcal{F}}g   \} = \{   g \in \mathbb{N}^{\omega} : \{ n:f(n)=g(n)  \} \in \mathcal{F}  \} \\= \{   g \in \mathbb{N}^{\omega} : \{ n:f(n)=g(n)  \} \in \{1,3,5\}\} $

I dont see an isomorphism. The cardinality of the domains are not the same I think. Or is that argument not correct.

Comment: **Hint:** Only principal ultrafilters have finite sets as elements.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{1,3,5\}\in\cal F$, we have that exactly one of the following is true: $\{1\}\in\cal F,\{3\}\in\cal F$ or $\{5\}\in\cal F$ (prove it).

WLOG, let $\{1\}\in \cal F$.

Now, given $f,g\in \cal N^\omega$, we have $f\sim_\cal F g\iff\{i\in\omega\mid f(i)=g(i)\}\in \cal F\iff f(1)=g(1)$.

That is, $\cal N^\omega/\cal F$ is decided completely by the index $1$ of each sequence.

Now, we can see that $F:\cal N\to\cal N^\omega/\cal F$ defined as $F(n)=[n']_\cal F$, where $n'$ is the constant function $n'(i)=n$, is isomorphism.